# One sided box shadow appearing under the div

Tags: html, css

Please see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/isuru_nan/M2KkX/) fiddle first. As you can see there's a slight shadow on the top border of the second section. I'm trying to get this shadow to the bottom border. I changed the CSS of the dive like this `box-shadow:0 8px 12px -6px #000;`. The shadow appears in the right position but the problem is if I remove the `display:none;` from the brown section, the shadow [isn't visible](http://jsfiddle.net/isuru_nan/t9UAx/) at all. It's [covered](http://jsfiddle.net/isuru_nan/TDUrb/) from the brown section.

I want the shadow to appear above the brown section. To give the feel that the brown section is under the beige one. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the section you want below

z-index:-1;

and to the section you want above

z-index:1;